# Bad relative path from remote machine on Apache server

Tags: wordpress, apache, path, xampp, relative-path

I installed last version of xampp 1.8.0 in a win 7 pc. I use apache, mysql and wordpress 3.4.2

I buit a new web site on htdocs and all work good locally (as a localhost , 192.168.1.10).
But when I try to access from another pc on the lan to 192.168.1.10 my web site it only shows a homepage without images and all path have link to localhost instead to 192.168.1.10.

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue ? what luck to my configuration ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your wordpress admin dashboard, make sure under **"General Settings"**, the **Site Address (URL)** and **WordPress Address (URL)** both say *"192.168.1.10"* instead of "*localhost"*.